# Angular 2 dropdownlist default values

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, primeng

I have a dropdownlist that get values from database and i want to have an default value like "select a item". How can i do that?

**HTML code**

```
<div class="ui-grid-row">
    <div class="ui-grid-col-2">
        Period :
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-col-4">
        <p-dropdown [options]="periodids" formControlName="periodid" [(ngModel)]="periodid" [autoWidth]="false" [style]="{'text-align': 'left'}"></p-dropdown>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Populate dropdownlist from database**

```
populatePeriod() {
    this.periodids = [];
    this.periodservice.getPeriods().then(returneddata => {
        for (let i = 0; i < returneddata.length; i++) {
            this.periodids.push({ label: returneddata[i].PeriodName, value: returneddata[i].Id });
        }
    });
    //console.log(this.periodids)
}
```

Comment: can u please add the <p-dropdown> component code here?

Comment: @sudheerKB Looks like it's the PrimeNG one. See the link in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41799180/3558960) below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example in the [PrimeNG documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown) suggests that you should add it to your options array:

```
populatePeriod() {
    this.periodids = [{ label: "Select an item...", value: null }]; // <-- here

    this.periodservice.getPeriods().then(returneddata => {
        for (let i = 0; i < returneddata.length; i++) {
            this.periodids.push({ label: returneddata[i].PeriodName, value: returneddata[i].Id });
        }
    });

    console.log(this.periodids)
}
```